# Create XML file from REST response

Tags: c#, xml

I have following method for making rest request which returns data in xml format -

```
public void Test()
    {
        string requestUri = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            requestUri = String.Format("uri/{0}?locales={1}", "test", "en-gb");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUri);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                // Want to create xml file here
                this.WriteToFile(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

How can I create a xml file from the response which I got from API?

Comment: response.ContentType = "text/xml";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the content is already XML just change `this.WriteToFile(content)` to

```
File.WriteAllText("foo.xml", content);
```

Also the `try {} catch (Exception e) {throw e}` is bad.  By rethrowing you loose stack information.  Simply do nothing and thrown exceptions will bubble up to your caller.

Comment: At which location will it create the file?

Comment: Basically at your `exe`/`dll` location.

Comment: At "working directory"; which by default is where you run the program from.  But you can use an fully qualified name, e.g. @"c:\mydir\foo.xml".  Note that @" tells the C# compiler to not interpret \ as an escape.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Thank you very much.